# search for a sentence in a paragraph

Tags: php, text-segmentation

How can I search a paragraph for one or more sentences using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will tell you whether a string exists within a string.

Comment: Well it'll tell you the first occurrence :P `strstr()` will give you a Boolean return, except I hear it is slower.

Comment: @alex `strstr` will return the part of the string starting at the match or `false`. `strpos` will return the starting index or `false`. You have to compare both to `=== false`. Not a big difference, really. :P

Comment: I should really read the docs before I say something... you're right :) Have a +1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look over [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php), maybe [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll probably want to use "[preg_match()](https://www.php.net/preg_match)" if possible (requires knowledge of regular expressions though). "strstr()" works too if you know exactly what you want to find.